# Trojan(Simple Client-Server in C)

Tags: c, security, firewall, virus, trojan

So I started network programming a few days ago, and I created a very simple trojan (Victims execute a client that create a connection to the hackers PC's and then Hackers can execute function of CMD by a simple system() command).

Basically my trojan works but I don't understand why my Anti-Virus doesn't detect it. I mean the only thing that possibly could have stopped my trojan is my firewall which detected an outgoing connection. So I don't understand why other trojans are detected but not this new one.

I can provide source code if needed, and I would like to emphasize that I do this only for educational purposes. I will never use any of this knowledge to attack anyone (Anyway I don't have enough skill), I just want to learn and understand :).

Comment: add the definition specific to your trojan to the AV database and try again. :-)

Comment: The police cant match your fingerprints if you have never been fingerprinted ...

Comment: @AlexK. I'm having an "Oh wait!" moment here.. Soo the fingerprints are comparable to the "Virus Database" that antivirus programs use? Basically, what hasn't been found can not be detected yet?

Comment: Yes, if the behaviour of the program itself does not trigger the AV directly, a signature database is all that's left to make an identification

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys, but how is it possible that a simple code like that isn't already in AV Database ? Even if the trojan must be executed by user(Unlikely to happen), I find this dangerous, I mean everybody can create a trojan and spread it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avira :

> AMES is using the Avira engine for virus detection. If the Avira
>   engine is not able to detect a virus, then the most likely cause could
>   be that this virus is brand new and cannot be detected yet. We would
>   greatly appreciate if you submit the suspicious file to us so we can
>   analyze it immediately. Our virus lab will subsequently send you a
>   feedback. If we cannot detect the suspicious file as a virus, we will
>   work on creating an update to make sure we detect the file in the
>   future.

AVG :

> Sometimes a new virus is not detected even if your AVG is fully up to
>   date. This happens when a threat has just been written or released, or
>   we’ve discovered it only very short time ago and are now working on an
>   update that will recognize and contain the virus.

DELL (https://powermore.dell.com/technology/teaching-your-computer-to-detect-new-viruses/) :

> Most antivirus programs use signatures — mathematically derived
>   strings or regular expressions of malware code — to detect viruses.
>   But that requires a lengthy process of finding malware in the wild,
>   getting a sample, analyzing it, generating a signature and adding it
>   to the repository that is pushed to users in anti-virus updates.

So it seems, like mentioned in the comments, that viruses are only detected when their signatures are recorded by the security software.

Here is a link on how you can use ClamAV to create your own signature : http://blog.adamsweet.org/?p=250

Comment: Ok so If I understand there is 2 "type" of detection: 1)Heuristic 2)Database but there isn't 1000way of doing a client-server in C, so why he isn't already in a database ? Thanks for the answer man, I will search more about this Clam AV, open source AV is really inetresting !

Comment: @LapinouSexy You are welcome. One bit different in your code to a known virus will make it not have a matching signature. So I guess that is why its not detected when the database approach is used.

Comment: So that's really dangerous, isn't it ? My trojan can potentially be dangerous even if I'm a newbie ? The only protection is the user behavior (And possibly the firewall), but with a bit of social engineering everybody can pass trough.

Comment: @LapinouSexy Not sure of your exact project, but it would be pretty hard to prove a simple c, client-server app was malicious just because it connected to an external address. Even deleting the contents of a HDD could be part of an apps normal behavior (like a disk partitioner)

Comment: I always thought It was very complex to write malicious programm, even simple one, but you are right. I have no exact project I just wanted to know more about security, but I'm still schocked that this kind of poor code would probably be able to "infect" a user. No I'm questioning myself, whats the point of making more complex trojan ? I know a lot of them introduce functions such as statistics, and other "funny" func like screencapture.

Answer (score 0):

It's not detected because most Antivirus are based on signatures (blacklisting) and that approach is basically not effective to stop malware because ir requires:

1. an Antivirus company to collect a sample, confirm it and write a
   signature for it;
2. Issue a database update;
3. People in general
   to update their virus database definitions.

Until steps 1-3 are taken, a virus is free to spread and attack your devices. Plus, since step 3 involves people cooperation (allow the antivirus to update) the attack window might not be so short.

It is generally accepted that the efficiency of signature-based antivirus is around 40%-45%.

In the last couple of years, antivirus companies are finally admitting that virus signatures are not the way to go, and they must change from that to behaviour analysis:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/2150743/antivirus-is-dead-says-maker-of-norton-antivirus.html